# Why does my object move in the wrong direction

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, coordinates

I have a made a simple program which is meant to move a ball left and right horizontally within a canvas. The user will use the left and right keys to move the ball accordingly by 5 pixels a time. If the  x coordinate of the ball is less than 40 or more than 240 then it will do nothing.

```
try:    
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as Tk

window = tk.Tk()
game_area = tk.Canvas(width=270, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                      bg="white")

ball = game_area.create_oval(10, 10, 24, 24, fill="red")
game_area.move(ball, 120, 4)
coords = 120

def move_left(event):
    global coords
    if coords < 40:
        pass
    else:
        coords = int(coords)- 5
        game_area.move(ball, coords, 4)
    game_area.update()

def move_right(event):
    global coords
    if coords > 240:
        pass
    else:
        coords = int(coords)+5
        game_area.move(ball, coords, 4)
    game_area.update()

window.bind("<Left>", move_left)
window.bind("<Right>", move_right)
game_area.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

However, pressing either key moves the ball towards the right (more than 5 pixels across) and off the screen despite the `if` function which is meant to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Tkinter Canvas documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method), the second argument to the `move` method, `dx`, is an offset. Try calling it like

```
game_area.move(ball, -5, 4)
```

Then you don't need the following line, either.

```
coords = int(coords)- 5
```

Comment: Thanks but although they move in the right direction, the ball still moves downwards and I want it to stay where it is in terms of the y axis.

Comment: @Ernxst The third argument, `dy`, is also an offset. Change that from 4 to 0.

Comment: Never mind! I just set 4 to 0 after re-reading what you posted.